# How to find and append class name with same integer

Tags: jquery, class, integer

I hope this isn't confusing. I have two lists:

```
<ul class="list_A">
  <li class="item_1"></li>
  <li class="item_2"></li>
  <li class="item_3"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list_B">
  <li class="item_1"></li>
  <li class="item_2"></li>
  <li class="item_3"></li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is when I hover over one of the list items, I want to have the list item with the same class in the other list have the same 'active' class appended to it. Which is what I can do with the below code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".item_1").hover(function () {
    $(".item_1").toggleClass('active');
  });
  $(".item_2").hover(function () {
    $(".item_2").toggleClass('active');
  });
  $(".item_2").hover(function () {
    $(".item_2").toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

However, how do I make it so I just have it find the appropriate class without having to duplicate the code for each and have it something like the below? The below doesn't work. :(

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var i = 0;
  i++;
  $(".item_" + i).hover(function () {
    $(".item_" + i).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `mouseenter` and the `mouseleave` events instead of `hover`, or else it will trigger every time you mouse moves over the element. And the toggle will trigger all the time.

This should work fine:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('li').mouseenter(function() {
        jQuery('.'+this.classList[0]).addClass('active');
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        jQuery('.'+this.classList[0]).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Skwal/43VxK/)**

**EDIT**: If you want to apply this to only specific lists, add a common class to each `ul` and update the first selector, like `jQuery('ul.myclass > li')`

Comment: This does work, but it affects all of the other lists on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like that :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    for ( var i = 1; i < 4; i++ ) {
        $(".item_" + i).hover(function () {
            $(".item_" + i).toggleClass('active');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it doesn't seem to be working.